# Networkx drawing label partially outside the box

Tags: python, networkx

Just draw a very simple 4-node network,

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
node1 = "116.251.211.248"
node2 = "5.79.100.165"
node3 = "http.anturis.com"
node4 = "s411993.ip-37-187-141.eu"
G.add_node(node1)
G.add_node(node2)
G.add_node(node3)
G.add_node(node4)
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(node1, node2, 0.742345), (node1, node3, 0.916954), (node1, node4, 0.662011), (node1, node4, 0.818537), (node2, node3, 0.947824), (node2, node4, 0.800774), (node3, node4, 0.928537)])
pos=nx.shell_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

My problem is the edge labels fall partially outside of the box

[image]

I am new to drawing with networkx. How do I add margins to the left and right so the full labels can be shown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an automated procedure for fixing the margins. You can adjust the margins by hand by calling `plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)`. Since you know the node positions (`pos`), you can add, say, an extra 25% on each side:

```
#Your code here....
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
x_values, y_values = zip(*pos.values())
x_max = max(x_values)
x_min = min(x_values)
x_margin = (x_max - x_min) * 0.25
plt.xlim(x_min - x_margin, x_max + x_margin)
plt.show()
```

[image]