# Add padding to NetworkX graph in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I want to render a `networkx` graph with `matplotlib`. The labels are somewhat long (around 10 - 50 characters each) and they tend to get cut off, preventing me from being able to read them. Is there a way I can make matplotlib "zoom out" the final rendering a bit so I can read all the text?

Below is my code, along with the rendered graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.Graph()
root_node = 'this is the root node'
G.add_node(root_node)
for other_node in [
  'test is an adjacent node',
  'test is another adjacent node',
  'test is yet another adjacent node',
  'test is the fourth adjacent node',
]:
  G.add_node(other_node)
  G.add_edge(root_node, other_node)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_size=8, node_color='white')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph rendering]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like creating an axis and setting a margin on that did the trick:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.margins(0.3)           

nx.draw(
  G,
  ax=ax1,
  with_labels=True,
  font_size=8,
  node_color='white',
)
```

[image: layout]

Comment: This solution will generally add whitespace and cut off the labels anyway. I would recommend setting the margins explicitly with `plt.xlim()` or `ax.set_slim()` as explained [here by DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459950/1735215).